# Vim like Perl IDE

Tags: perl, ide, vim, vim-plugin

I use Vim and vim-script "[perl-support](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=556)" for Perl programming. But in the perlsupport like Perl Vim IDE I couldn't find a feature for show all functions and variables in my script. Are there any other useful vim scripts for this goal or how I can reach it with other approaches?
Thanks for a response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Tagbar plugin](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/).  It uses CTAGS, which is a Unix standard way of indexing symbols in source code for a variety of languages.  The plugin page has details on setting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for of topic. this is not plugin that show function/variables.

Use [perlomni.vim](https://github.com/c9s/perlomni.vim)

This provides code completion that can show candidates by analysing contexts. For example,

```
use Foo;
my $foo = Foo->new;
$foo->
```

perlomni show method functions. it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other suggestions in combination with [NeoComplCache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache). This plugin can integrate them all, including some other nice completion functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To show function list you can use plugin of Dave Vehrs [from vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=397) or [from ghub](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ShowFunc.vim)

From plugin description:

> This script creates a hyper link list of all the functions, subroutines, classes, macros or procedures in a  single file or all currently open windows and displays them in a dynamically sized cwindow.

It works fine with perl.